# How can i detect certificate issue programmatically in Ruby

Tags: ruby, ssl, openssl, certificate, ssl-certificate

I have cases that a few customers get an error while posting to our server (HTTPS). This is the error:

```
SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=error: certificate verify failed (unable to get local issuer certificate)
```

I can use this method to detect what fails in the certificate chain:

```
openssl s_client -connect <url>:443 -CAfile <path/cacert.pem>
```

But, not all customers are willing to download and install openssl. So, I want to add this test using ruby code (we already have ruby installed on the customer's computer).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This ruby code should do the work:

```
require 'openssl'
require 'socket'

CA_CERT = "<your-path-to-cert-file. e.g. cacert.pem>"

def verify_host(host)
  puts "Connecting to: #{host} ..."

  ctx = OpenSSL::SSL::SSLContext.new(:TLSv1_2)

  ctx.ca_file = CA_CERT
  ctx.verify_mode = OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_PEER
  ctx.verify_callback = lambda do | preverify_ok, cert_store |
    cert = cert_store.current_cert
    puts "subject: #{cert.subject}, issuer: #{cert.issuer}, valid: #{preverify_ok}"
    preverify_ok
  end

  socket = TCPSocket.new host, 443

  ssl_socket = OpenSSL::SSL::SSLSocket.new socket, ctx
  ssl_socket.hostname = host
  puts "SSL Version: #{ssl_socket.ssl_version}"

  ssl_socket.connect

  ssl_socket.sysclose
  socket.close
rescue => ex
  puts ex
end
```

Sample usage:
verify_host('s3.amazonaws.com')

Output:

```
Connecting to: s3.amazonaws.com ...
SSL Version: TLSv1.3
subject: /C=IE/O=Baltimore/OU=CyberTrust/CN=Baltimore CyberTrust Root, issuer: /C=IE/O=Baltimore/OU=CyberTrust/CN=Baltimore CyberTrust Root, valid: true
subject: /C=US/O=DigiCert Inc/OU=www.digicert.com/CN=DigiCert Baltimore CA-2 G2, issuer: /C=IE/O=Baltimore/OU=CyberTrust/CN=Baltimore CyberTrust Root, valid: true
subject: /C=US/ST=Washington/L=Seattle/O=Amazon.com, Inc./CN=s3.amazonaws.com, issuer: /C=US/O=DigiCert Inc/OU=www.digicert.com/CN=DigiCert Baltimore CA-2 G2, valid: true
```